# Get the Text for the hyperlink with a different Icon

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the text for the hyperlink which has a tag icon "ins" beside it.When I write the below code, it prints the "?" instead of the text.screen shot is attached for the application under test![Screen shot].Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

List links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("ins"));

```
    System.out.println("the number of movie links in the site is "+links.size());

    for (int i = 1; i<=links.size(); i=i+1)

    {

        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());

    }
```

Comment: Post your html snippet of this part.

Comment: do you want to get text for hyperlink?

Comment: for hyperlink text if its contained in `href` attribute use `links.get(i).getAttribute("href")` or if it doesnt work provide the html...

Comment: <h3>
<a class="program-link" title="Transamérica" href="/br/programas/transamerica-2005">
<span>
<time>10:15</time>
<ins class="icon movie">΢</ins>
Transamérica
</span>
</a>
</h3>

Comment: @OpenJDK - yes I want the text for the hyperlink

Comment: please see if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633595/how-to-get-the-text-of-the-hyperlink-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so u can reach to the element/s using `//ins[@class='icon movie']/ancestor::a` and then use

```
for (int i = 0; i<links.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Also in your loop u r omitting the first element in list. Is it by mistake or needed?
Also u can use enhanced for loop for this purpose as:

```
for (WebElement webelement : links){
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
}
```

And if you are using the new Java 8 u can explore the new features as:

```
links.forEach(new Consumer<WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(WebElement t) {
        System.out.println(t.getAttribute("href"));
    }
});
```

Comment: //ins[@class='icon movie']/ancestor::a works to retreive the text from the hyperlink